# Parentheses in sqldatareader

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a DB using SQLLite and I'm using C#. I do querys and It works, but when the query has `( )` it fails and give a excpetion about the SQL Syntax.

I create a function that helps me with the querys using `SQLiteDataReader`

```
    public SQLiteDataReader SQLExecuteReader(string sqlStatement, SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection)
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlStatement, sqliteConnection);
        return command.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

And I use it this way:

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = SQLExecuteReader("--SQL QUERY--", sqliteConnection);
```

In my case I am using a query to compare two tables with the same structure.
When the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Table2
```

it works.

But when the query is

```
(   SELECT * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Or

```
(SELECT * FROM Table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Table2
```

It fails.

What am I missing and why it fails when I use `(   )` in the query?

Comment: How does it fail? Error? Wrong result?

Comment: Exception saying invalid SQL syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to execute this query,

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * FROM Table2
) a
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table2 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * FROM Table1
) b
```

Comment: A and b are called alias. Remove ALL from UNION and execute again. ALL keeps duplicates from the result so ny removing it, records are now unique.